# Is there a tool to track edits that were made?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, editing, versioning

Is there a tool/report that keeps track of what edits were made that I could run prior to or after reconciling my versions?

This would help me to know if there are any changes I need to make to any maps or databases that are disconnected from our SDE.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: Are you not using the built in editor tracking? **Just realized this is a month old.

Comment: yes, I'm using that, however, I'm wondering if there is something I could create that would loop through all of my feature classes and give a list of modified records, sorted by feature class.

Comment: Yeah, I would use a searchcursor on the different feature classes and make some type of report.

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing a check-out database and reconciling to SDE, in your disconnected edit tools there is 'Export to Delta' this (from memory) has a table of the deleted records and a feature class of the added records.

Modified features occur in the delete table and in the adds feature class.
Deleted records occur only in the delete table.
Added records occur only in the adds feature class.

I had to do this once where a well meaning SDE admin removed my version that coincided with a check out and then do the delete and add manually.